# Problem with creating tables for Plugin

Tags: plugins, wpdb, sql

I hope someone can help me.

I try to execute this code to install the tables for my Plugin. But for some reason it doesn't work (Doesn't appear in my wordpress database) and I can't find out why. Can someone help me?

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Test Plugin 
    PLUGIN URL: 
    Description: Dashboard fuer die Kundenverwaltung
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Maxime Buelow
*/
function activate(){
        global $wpdb;
        
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        
        //$verb = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test4');
        $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . "Veranstaltung";
        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "Personen";
        $table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "Sponsor";
        $table_name4 = $wpdb->prefix . "sponkunde";
        
        //$wpdb->query("CREATE DATABASE eBagDB");
        $query1 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name1 . "(
        ver_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        VeranstaltungName varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        $query2 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name2 . "(
        pers_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Datum DATE, 
        Passwort varchar(255) UNIQUE, 
        Vorname varchar(255), 
        Nachname varchar(255), 
        Anrede varchar(255), 
        LoeschDatum DATE, 
        fkVer_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkVer_id) REFERENCES Veranstaltung(Ver_id), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (pers_id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        $query3 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name3 . "(
        sp_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Code varchar(255), 
        Name varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (sp_id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        $query4 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name4 . "(
        fkPers_id int(11), 
        fkSp_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkPers_id) REFERENCES Personen(pers_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkSp_id) REFERENCES sponsor(sp_id)
        ) $charset_collate;"; 
        
        /*$wpdb->query($query1);
        $wpdb->query($query2);
        $wpdb->query($query3);
        $wpdb->query($query4);*/
        
        //$ergCrDB = $wpdb->get_results($createDB, OBJECT);
        
        //$ergCrTbVer = $wpdb->get_results($createTbVer, OBJECT);
        /*$ergCrTbPers = $wpdb->get_results($createTbPers, OBJECT);
        $ergCrTbSp = $wpdb->get_results($createTbPersSp, OBJECT);
        $ergCrTbPersSp = $wpdb->get_results($createTbSponsor, OBJECT);*/
        
        dbDelta($query1);
        dbDelta($query2);
        dbDelta($query3);
        dbDelta($query4);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activate');?>
```

**UPDATE**

The issue has been partly resolved so far. In my wp-config was the wrong database chosen. Thanks for the help so far! :)

I got another question: Now the table creation works, but only the first table is created. The other 3 not. Does somebody know why?

My Code now looks like this:

```
function artok_activate(){
    global $wpdb;
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    $charset_collate                = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_Veranstaltung            = $wpdb->prefix . 'Veranstaltung';
    $table_Personen                 = $wpdb->prefix . 'Personen';
    $table_Sponsor                  = $wpdb->prefix . 'Sponsor';
    $table_SponKunde                = $wpdb->prefix . 'SponKunde';
    
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_Veranstaltung'" ) != $table_Veranstaltung ) {
        $tableVer_Crea = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_Veranstaltung . '(
        ver_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        VeranstaltungName varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
        )' . $charset_collate . ';';
        dbDelta( $tableVer_Crea );
        $success = empty($wpdb->last_error);
        
        return $success;
    }
    
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_Personen'" ) != $table_Personen ) {
        $tablePers_Crea = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_Personen . "(
        pers_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Datum DATE, 
        Passwort varchar(255) UNIQUE, 
        Vorname varchar(255), 
        Nachname varchar(255), 
        Anrede varchar(255), 
        LoeschDatum DATE, 
        fkVer_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkVer_id) REFERENCES wp_Veranstaltung(Ver_id), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (pers_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        
        dbDelta($tablePers_Crea);
        
        $success = empty($wpdb->last_error);
        
        return $success;
    }
    
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_Sponsor'" ) != $table_Sponsor) {
        $tableSp_Crea = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_Sponsor . "(
        sp_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Code varchar(255), 
        Name varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (sp_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        dbDelta( $tableSp_Crea );
        $success = empty($wpdb->last_error);
        
        return $success;
    }
    
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_SponKunde'" ) != $table_SponKunde ) {
        $tableSpKu_Crea = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_SponKunde . "(
        fkPers_id int(11), 
        fkSp_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkPers_id) REFERENCES wp_Personen(pers_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkSp_id) REFERENCES wp_Sponsor(sp_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        dbDelta( $tableSpKu_Crea );
        $success = empty($wpdb->last_error);
        
        return $success;
    }
}   
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'artok_activate' );
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way this is structured: `FOREIGN KEY(fkVer_id) REFERENCES wp_Veranstaltung(Ver_id),` Try removing that line from the second table and see if that works and look through every line - if there's an error at any point it'll stop executing further, so start with the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Artok, your concatenation is incorrect...  You forgot to continue the pattern with your $charset_collate variable.

If we look at `$query1` we see this:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
) $charset_collate;";
```

What we should see is this:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
)" . $charset_collate . ";";
```

You should also avoid giving your functions generic names, I recognize you may have just changed it to `activate()` for the sake of not posting the actual name of your function here, but I see a lot of generic naming when I get work submitted to me and it creates conflicts.

```
function artok_activate(){
        global $wpdb;
        
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        
        //$verb = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test4');
        $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . "Veranstaltung";
        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "Personen";
        $table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "Sponsor";
        $table_name4 = $wpdb->prefix . "sponkunde";
        
        //$wpdb->query("CREATE DATABASE eBagDB");
        $query1 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name1 . "(
        ver_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        VeranstaltungName varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        $query2 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name2 . "(
        pers_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Datum DATE, 
        Passwort varchar(255) UNIQUE, 
        Vorname varchar(255), 
        Nachname varchar(255), 
        Anrede varchar(255), 
        LoeschDatum DATE, 
        fkVer_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkVer_id) REFERENCES Veranstaltung(Ver_id), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (pers_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        $query3 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name3 . "(
        sp_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        Code varchar(255), 
        Name varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (sp_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";";
        $query4 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name4 . "(
        fkPers_id int(11), 
        fkSp_id int(11), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkPers_id) REFERENCES Personen(pers_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(fkSp_id) REFERENCES sponsor(sp_id)
        )" . $charset_collate . ";"; 
        
        /*$wpdb->query($query1);
        $wpdb->query($query2);
        $wpdb->query($query3);
        $wpdb->query($query4);*/
        
        //$ergCrDB = $wpdb->get_results($createDB, OBJECT);
        
        //$ergCrTbVer = $wpdb->get_results($createTbVer, OBJECT);
        /*$ergCrTbPers = $wpdb->get_results($createTbPers, OBJECT);
        $ergCrTbSp = $wpdb->get_results($createTbPersSp, OBJECT);
        $ergCrTbPersSp = $wpdb->get_results($createTbSponsor, OBJECT);*/
        
        dbDelta($query1);
        dbDelta($query2);
        dbDelta($query3);
        dbDelta($query4);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'artok_activate');
```

I hope this fixes the issue for you.  :-)

**Update:**

When I tested adding one of the tables to a plugin I'm working on that also registers custom tables on activation, it worked.
[image: Table successfully added to DB.]

Here's how the functions work for me:

```
function artok_db_create_tables() {
    global $wpdb
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    $charset_collate        = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name1            = $wpdb->prefix . 'Veranstaltung';
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name1'" ) != $table_name1 ) {
        $table1_sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_name1 . '(
        ver_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        VeranstaltungName varchar(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY  (ver_id)
        )' . $charset_collate . ';';
        dbDelta( $table1_sql );
    }//table_name1
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'artok_db_create_tables' );
```

I've only run it once for the first table, but you would then just repeat the pattern. I've added a condition that first checks if the table already exists before attempting to add it a second time.

Comment: Thank you :) But the issue seems to be still the same :( I look into the Database Wordpress, but still no tables have been created while activating the plugin, no matter if with or without prefix.

Comment: Did you fix the concatenation as well?

Comment: Especially this yep, the concatenation around the $charset_collate is now the same.

Comment: I updated my answer with a fully working snippet.  This snippet successfully runs when I add it to one of my plugins.

Comment: Hm I did it exactly this way now. But there is still no table in my wordpress database. Maybe there is something wrong with the database?

Comment: That I can't tell you.  The only thing I do different is that I've started adding a record in the options table that specifies the DB version, that way in case I ever need to update my DB structure I can target it based on version.  But that's not in any way related to what actually happens with the table creation.

Is there any other code in your plugin file that could be throwing an error and perhaps interrupting this.

Comment: I created another plugin file just to test your code snippet, nothing additionally. So I think there might be some problem with my database. No tables are shown in the WordPress database. Only the other standard tables with wp_ prefix.

Comment: Hi. me again :) Thanks for your help so far. I updated my problem, i hope you can see it.